# Remove lines from AWK output

Tags: sed, awk, xargs

I would like to remove lines that have less than 2 columns from a file:

```
awk '{ if (NF < 2) print}' test
one two
```

Is there a way to store these lines into variable and then remove it with `xargs` and `sed`, something like

```
awk '{ if (NF < 2) VARIABLE}' test | xargs sed -i /VARIABLE/d
```

Comment: Please show examples for input/desired output.

Comment: Basically I would like to remove some entries from Apache logs that doesn't much log format specified in Awstats.

Comment: Would you like to split the file, and redirect rows with NF > 2 to one file and rows with NF<=2 to another file?

Comment: Just to be clear: your question is ambiguous. The text says "less than 2" (i.e. NF < 2) and your example code tests for NF <=2.

Comment: This has been corrected now and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to split the input into two files (named "pass" and "fail"), based on condition:

```
awk '{if (NF > 1 ) print > "pass"; else print > "fail"}' input
```

If you simply want to filter/remove lines with NF < 2:

```
awk '(NF > 1){print}' input
```

Answer (score 2):

#### GNU sed

> I would like to remove lines that have less than 2 columns

less than 2 = remove lines with only one column

```
sed -r '/^\s*\S+\s+\S+/!d' file
```